# C# headless chrome from Process Start not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I need to call headless chrome from a net core console application. But with this code the aplication run and get stuck doing nothing and printing nothin, also the pdf is not created. The same arguments in the terminal are working as expected.

```
public static bool TakeScreenshot2()
        {
            try
            {
                var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "google-chrome",
                    Arguments = "--headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=final.pdf http://www.google.com/",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

                var proc = new Process { StartInfo = procStartInfo };
                proc.Start();

                var output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                string error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(error);

                return proc.ExitCode == decimal.Zero ? true : false;
            }
            finally
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you comapre ExitCode to decimal ? its Int32, return proc.ExitCode == 0 is ok

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the process to finish

```
var proc = new Process { StartInfo = procStartInfo };
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

You can check if it was success also with `proc.ExitCode` after it exit

If you dont want to block the thread unit it finish you can run it with, you function needs to be async

```
await Task.Run(() => proc.WaitForExit());
```

or to use the Process event `Exited`

Comment: Added the WaitForExit line but still the same, it just start but never finish, its like something is blocking the execution

Comment: @BraisRV You dont have a catch block, are you sure that you dont have exception that you are missing when you try to run ? try add catch and Console.WriteLine the exception message